# Silverlight 'Business Application' Template Missing

Tags: silverlight

I'm looking for the template in VS 2010 for creating a Silverlight Business Application.  However, I only have the following templates available to me:

- Silverlight Application
- Silverlight Class Library
- Silverlight Navigation Application
- Silverlight Test Unit Application

How do find/install the Business Application project template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Silverlight Business Application project template comes with WCF RIA Services. Make sure you have it installed. Otherwise, you can get it from [here](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/advanced-techniques/wcf-ria-services/get-started-with-wcf-ria-services)

Hope this helps :)

**Update**: @hughesdan solved the problem (see comments below), and noted something very important: **make sure you've selected .NET 4.0 from the "targetted framework" dropdown**

Comment: I ran the installations from that page (1.1 and 1.3 specifically...skipping the optional silverlight 5).  However, I still do not have a template option in VS for creating Business Application.

Comment: I figured out what the problem was.  In the template gallery I was looking at 3.5 templates.  Once I selected .NET 4.0 from the drop-down menu I saw the Business Application template I was looking for.  I'm going to accept your answer.  To anyone else who comes across this post...be sure you're looking in the .NET 4.0 gallery and not 3.5 by mistake.